# Does Visio 2019 install an equivalent to AxInterop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx?

Tags: wpf, visio

I'm working with an example app for Visio integration in WPF apps. The sample app references AxInterop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx

The Virtual Machine I develop on is locked down and I cannot copy any .dll's onto it.
It does have Visio 2019 installed on it though.

Based on this, is there an equivalent to AxInterop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx available on a machine with Visio 2019 installed ?

Comment: Check the [GAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/gac?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) on the target machine.

Comment: @mm8 This assembly is auto-generated by Visio Studio when you drop Visio Drawing ActiveX to a form, there is probably no point in checking GAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assembly you mentioned is **auto-generated by Visual Studio** when you add a Visio control to a form (i.e. drag-drop it from a toolbox).

Most probably, you have a mismatch between the version of Visio installed and your Visual Studio version. Like, Visio is 32bit, and you are using Visual Studio 2022 (64bit), or Visio is 64bit, and you are using Visual Studio 2019 (32bit). Therefore, Visio control does not appear in the toolbox in Visual Studio, and you can't use it normally.

In principle, it should be as simple as this (dropping from the toolbox). This may be the reason they tasked you with this:

[image]

Some related troubleshooter:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/visio/cannot-add-visio-drawing-control

I think, for simplicity, you could just use matching versions. Like, Visual Studio 2022 and Visio x64. Or Visual Studio 2019 and Visio x86. But if this is an administrative problem (you are not allowed to install or uninstall anything) then it can't be helped I guess.